# Rename Point in CATIA vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

I would like to rename a point in **CATIA** using `vb.NET`.
This is my code:

```
Dim myPoint As MECMOD.GeometricElement

myProductDoc.Selection.Search("(Name='ABC' & CATGmoSearch.Point),all")
myPartNumber = myProductDoc.Product.Products.Item(i + 1).Name
myPartNumber = myPartNumber.Substring(0, myPartNumber.LastIndexOf(".", myPartNumber.LastIndexOf(".") - 1))

myPoint = myProductDoc.Selection.Item2(2).Value
myPoint.Name = "AB_" & myPartNumber

Problem is in this line:
myPoint = myProductDoc.Selection.Item2(2).Value
```

Can anybody help?

THX

Comment: I don't get it.. What do you mean with "rename"?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the point is now ABC and is supposed to be change to AB.
I guess that the Problem is in this line:

Dim myPoint As MECMOD.GeometricElement

This is a 3D Point and GeometricELement is only for 2D Elements. But I don't know what to choose für a 3D Element.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

It is not : Dim myPoint As MECMOD.GeometricElement
But: Dim myPoint As MECMOD.HybridShape